# R programming - vector identifier field

Tags: r, vector, record, identifier

I am creating an R vector with a single row of data, where the first column is a text ID, and the following 30 columns are numeric.

```
v <- read.csv("file", header=T)
```

When I print the vector, the first column shows up but I cannot seem to access that column. Can anyone explain how this happens?

If I had more than 1 record in the csv file, it would contain different project IDs - is there a way to use this field in equations with a vector or do I need a matrix or data frame?

Here is an example of the vector print, where the "116882-000" is the project id field from the csv file.  The project id field had a header in the csv, and I understand that vectors cannot be both text and numeric but just surprised I am getting the project id field and thought there may be a use for it:

```
                 X.1       X0        X1        X2        X3
116882-000 479958710 -4071241 541578270 584095699 649451813
```

note the column header for the project id did not import, but there is a header for each of the values in the vector - hope they are lining up correctly.
Seemed to be same issue with read.table

Comment: Worth adding a sample of your csv file just in case there's something wrong in it.

Comment: Thank you to all. I had the row.names parameter set so it was considering the first column as a row name and not a data field.  Solved!